# React Native Mapping through Array of Objects gives blank values

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to loop over a simple array of objects and display the content inside Text tag. The looping is being done but the actual content is not displayed on the screen.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
      const initialArr = [
        {
          id: 1,
          color: "blue",
          text: "text1"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          color: "red",
          text: "text2"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          color: "green",
          text: "text3"
        }
      ];
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {initialArr.map((prop, key) => {
        return (
          <Text key={key}>{prop[1]}</Text>
        );
     })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Within the map function, wouldn't ```prop``` be an object, not an array? Instead reading the ```[1]``` property, try rendering ```{prop.text]```

Comment: Ah, my bad. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
render() {
  const initialArr = [
    { id: 1, color: "blue", text: "text1" },
    { id: 2, color: "red", text: "text2" },
    { id: 3, color: "green", text: "text3"}
  ];

  var textInputComponents = initialArr.map((prop, key) => {
    return (
      <Text key={key}>{prop.text}</Text>
    );
  })

  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {textInputComponents}
  </View>
  );
}
```

Apart from John_mc's answer, instead of using inline mapping, you can also split the mapping operation, to improve readability and maintainability